# NpgSQL insert file path containing backslashes "\\"

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio-2010, npgsql

I am trying to create a record containing the path to a file. The insertion is done into a `Postgres` database where UTF8 is enabled, using the `NpqSQL` driver.

My table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE images
(
    id serial,
    file_location character varying NOT NULL
)
```

My SQL statement including the code that executes it (boiled down to a minimum):

```
string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO images (file_location) VALUES ('\\2010')";

NpgsqlConnection dbConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
dbConnection.Open();
NpgsqlCommand dbCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(sqlStatement , dbConnection);
int result = dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
dbConnection.Close();
```

When using **pgAdmin** to insert the above statement, it works fine. Using the **NpgSQL** driver through **Visual Studio C#**, it fails with this exception:

```
"ERROR: 22021: invalid byte sequence for encoding \"UTF8\": 0x81"
```

As **Milen** accurately explains, Postgres interprets the statement as an `octal` number (\o201 == 0x81).

As **Milen** also describes, the `E` infront of the path doesn't help.

So a quick recap: Why is NpqSQL stopping my insertion of the `\\2010`?

Comment: Have you read "4.1.2.1. String Constants" and "4.1.2.2. String Constants with C-Style Escapes" from the manual (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)?

Comment: @Milen: "Any other character following a backslash is taken literally. Thus, to include a backslash character, write two backslashes (\\\).". My logic tells me, that the '\\' is considered before the octal byte value '\2...'?

Comment: You haven't showed the real code so I suppose your interpreter/compiler interprets the double backslashes as an escaped backslash and then Postgres sees only one backslash followed by some digits. Which is it interprets as an octal number (o201,x81).

Comment: BTW about the "escape" string constants (strings starting with "E") - in your case they are completely unnecessary. In standard SQL backslash has no special meaning.

Comment: Are you using parameters? Npgsql should be handling escaped strings for your automatically. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Milen** deserves credit for leading me to the answer - thanks!

Appearantly NpgSQL performs one escape-iteration before inserting my SQL statement into Postgres. Thus to solve my problem, I replaced all the occurances of my backslashes with two backslashes instead:

```
string path = ... my path ...
path = path.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO images (file_location) VALUES ('" + path + "')";
```

Comment: C# uses the backslash (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) for escape sequences in normal strings. Thus to include a single backslash in a string you need two backslashes. But there exist "Verbatim string literals", prefixed with @, which could be helpful in this case (@"c:\Docs\Source\a.txt" vs. "c:\\Docs\\Source\\a.txt").

Comment: @Milen: Yeah the @ is normally very useful, but when the string is passed to NpgSQL the backslashes are removed :(

Answer (score 4):

(Realised my comments look like an answer so converted them accordingly.)

You haven't showed the real code so I suppose your interpreter/compiler interprets the double backslashes as an escaped backslash and then Postgres sees only one backslash followed by some digits. Which is it interprets as a octal byte value (octal 201 = hexadecimal 81).

About the "escape" string constants (strings starting with "E") - in your case they are completely unnecessary. In standard SQL backslash has no special meaning.

Please read "4.1.2.1. String Constants" and "4.1.2.2. String Constants with C-Style Escapes" from the manual (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) for details.

Comment: @Milen: Thanks for your efforts. I've edited my original post and included the code. I still cannot understand though, where the '\\' is converted to '\'.